# How to prevent importing specific framework on Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, architecture

Lets say I created swift frameworks on Xcode like below

- Wireframe
- Entity

I kept all frameworks "Frameworks and Libraries" section on Xcode empty.
[image]

[image]

[image]

However I'm still able to access both from Wireframe -> Entity and Entity -> Wireframe.

```
// A class belongs to Wireframe

import Entity // <- This does not raise error

public class MyRouter: NSObject {
    public func hoge() {
        let board = Book()
    }
}
```

```
// A class belongs to Entity

import Wireframe // <- This does not raise error

public class Book: NSObject {

    public var name: String = ""
    
    public override init() {
        super.init()
        let router = Wireframe.MyRouter()
    }
}
```

Is it possible to prevent importing specific framework to another framework(like showing compile error if tried by writing "import ") that I can assure architecture is not messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode automatically links to frameworks that Swift imports, as described [here](https://milen.me/writings/auto-linking-on-ios-and-macos/). But you can disable this with the “Link Frameworks Automatically” build setting.